# escaping special characters like & in android xml

Tags: android

```
<string name="app_name">something & something</string>
```

gives an error. How can i escape this?

Is this correct

```
<string name="app_name">something &amp; something</string>
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Try reading this page: http://www.xmlnews.org/docs/xml-basics.html it looks like it contains the answer you are looking for.

In summary, here is the list of escaped characters and the escape code

```
Character  Predeclared Entity
&          &amp;
<          &lt;
>          &gt;
"          &quot;
'          &apos;
```

Referenced from the link.

Comment: It would be better to at least quote the answer, so it's here.

Comment: Who wants to read  xml documentation... I just want to read it all in one place, here on the stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 15):

For me  &quot ; didin't work so I used \"" and this character was escaped.

Comment: I can see a whitespace in `&quot ;`.

Comment: This escaping is for escaping XML files, not java.

Comment: please explain how you used this to escape? just show us where you placed &

Answer (score 5):

Well in Android XML simply adding the Predeclared entities didn't work in my case, needed to add a backslash before it.
So in order to escape `something & something` use:

```
<string name="app_name">something \&amp; something</string>
```

In the case of apostrophe and quotes simply using a backslash works too.
Like for escaping something like `"That's it"` you can simply use:

```
<string name="demo">\"That\'s it\"</string>
```

instead of the usual

```
<string name="demo">\&quot;That\&apos;s it\&quot;</string>
```

Hope this will be of help when someone like me stumbles on this question.