# String resources including '<'

Tags: android, xml, string

I want my string resource to be a a section of javascript this contains the character '<' when I add it xml treats it as the start of a tag. How do I include < in my string without it being seen as part of a tag?

Answer (score 8):

```
Entity                     Character    Name    Usage
left angle bracket            <          lt     &lt;
right angle bracket           >          gt     &gt;
ampersand                     &          amp    &amp;
single quote or apostrophe    '          apos   &apos;
double quote or speech mark   "          quot   &quot;
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use an entity for the character. In this case `&lt;` should be substituted for `<`.

Comment: I knew it would be something like that. Do you have a list of these I could not find them?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056481/escaping-special-characters-like-in-android-xml) references a complete list of characters which need to be escaped with their entities.

Comment: @Lawtonj94 Check [this](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php). It may helpful.