# Cannot set button text to "<<<"

Tags: java, android, button, settext

I'm trying to set the text of a button to "<<<" from my xml but I get an "Error:(20) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:text="<<<"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So I jumped over to my strings.xml to enter it in there and that clearly won't work.

```
<string name="abc"> <<< </string>
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are html entities, works in android studio as well:

```
> can be replaced with &gt;
< can be replaced with &lt;
" can be replaced with &quot;, &ldquo; or &rdquo;
' can be replaced with &apos;, &lsquo; or &rsquo;
} can be replaced with &#125;
& can be replaced with &amp;
space can be replaced with &#160;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `&gt;` for `>`, `&lt;` for `<` , `&amp;` for `&` ,`&apos;` for `'` , `&quot;` for `"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
< (less-than)                     &#60; or &lt;
> (greater-than)                  &#62; or &gt;
& (ampersand)                     &#38; or &amp;
' (apostrophe or single quote)    &#39; or &apos;
" (double-quote)                  &#34; or &quot;
```

please check out these links :

[Predefined entities in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

[Using Special Characters in XML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/bc4j/developing_bc_projects/obcCustomXml.htm)

[Stackoverflow - escaping special characters like & in android xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056481/escaping-special-characters-like-in-android-xml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)